# python script from youtube video doesn't work

Tags: python

I am trying to learn python from this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RrPZza_vZ3w

In the video they have given the viewers a script to run:

```
">>> import urllib"

">>> u = urllib.urlopen('http://ctabustracker.com/bustime/map/getBusesForRoute.jsp?route=22')"

">>> data = u.read()"

">>> f = open('rt22.xml','wb')"

">>> f.write(data)"

">>> f.close()"
```

which pulls up data from a website and saves it in an xml file. But when I check the xml file I only get this: XML Parsing Error: no element found

Comment: what code are you using to parse?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I don't know what parse means. I am using IDLE for python 2.7.6 and using firefox to open up the xml file

Comment: I actually watched that video myself a while back, your code gets the xml file just fine so the issue must be in the next part, I added the code I used, use it to go along with the video or as a reference against your own code, I am sorry I don't have time to add comments to it now but it is pretty straight forward and hopefully should help you a bit/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure this is all the code needed for the video, It might help as a reference.

```
import urllib
import webbrowser
import time
from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse

u = urllib.urlopen("http://ctabustracker.com/bustime/map/getBusesForRoute.jsp?route=22")
data = u.read()

with open("rt22.xml", "wb") as f:
    f.write(data)
    f.close()

office_lat = 41.980262
doc = parse("rt22.xml")


def distance(lat1, lat2):
    'Return approx miles between lat1 and lat2'
    return 69 * abs(lat1 - lat2)


def check_bus_location():
    for bus in doc.findall("bus"):
        if bus.findtext("lat") >= office_lat:
            latitude = float(bus.findtext("lat"))
            longitude = float(bus.findtext("lon"))
            bus_id = (bus.findtext("id"))
            direction = bus.findtext("d")
            north_buses = [[bus_id, latitude, longitude]]
            if direction.startswith("North"):
                print('%s %s %0.2f miles' % (bus_id, direction, distance(latitude, office_lat)))
                for bus in north_buses:
                    if distance(float(latitude), office_lat) < 0.5:
                        print(webbrowser.open(
                            'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=500x500&sensor=false&markers=|%f,%f' % (
                                latitude, longitude)))


while True:
    check_bus_location()
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: thanks but how do I run this code? Do I have to type it line after line in IDLE?

Comment: better to type it in and try to understand what it is doing by adding print statements and watching the video using the code as a reference, don't just copy paste or it will defeat the purpose! When you understand it, you can run it in a script or any way you please

Comment: thanks it worked. I only typed till "doc = parse("rt22.xml")" and got the desired output. can u pls explain why it didn't work earlier?

Comment: You have to call the parse method on the xml file.  I will add a few comments later to explain what is happening.